# Unable to add compiler flag in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, compiler-flags

Hi i recently installed Xcode 5 but cant add compiler flags to it. I want to add compiler flag for automatic reference counting but when I go to build phases=>Compile sources=> .m file and double click on it or press enter while selecting it, the popup to enter compiler flag does not appear.

How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe it's a glitch, it wasn't working for me either. Then I created a new Xcode project from scratch, and in that one was working fine.

I came back to the one that wasn't working and now it started accepting changes.

Make also sure that the column "Complier Flags" it's not hidden to the far right.

Edit:I don't know if it's your case but there's definitely a glitch. If you load the project settings in a narrow window (say in assistant mode) the flags column won't appear, and the popup text where you are supposed to enter the flags won't show. If I go to standard editor, then it behaves normally.

Comment: You are 100% correct, thats a glitch, compiler flags was hidden, i stretched the window, it showed, i double clicked it and it worked. Thanks. I will report this to apple now.

Comment: In my case you gave me a clue.
It was hidden to the far right end!!!
Else it's in the same place as it was/is!!!
Like shown in the bellow link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/1752988