# Using JsonKit in Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, jsonkit

I using Xcode 5.0 and i want to use jsonKit to parser content, but i can't find where to place
:

> -fno-arc-objc

It will display :

> if __has_feature(objc_arc) error JSONKit does not support Objective-C
>   Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) endif

Well, I did add the JSONKit classes (JSONKit.h & JSONKit.h) but in the .m file, I have a lot of warnings & compil's error's.
I using refactor to convert to objective-c arc but it seem not OK..

Comment: You add the `fno-objc-arc` flag to the compiler options. But why are you using JSONKit when you can use `NSJSONSerialization` which is "built-in" (in the sense that it's part of the Foundation framework available by default)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the flag to the compiler options you have to go through Project->Build Phases->Compile Sources, and double click on each of the files where you want to put the flag :

[image]
Beware that there is a strange glitch depending on where the settings window is loaded :

[Unable to add compiler flag in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333316/unable-to-add-compiler-flag-in-xcode-5/19333353#19333353)